# benefit of using custom certificates vs a secret key to secure an API

Tags: web-services, rest, certificate

Looking at the way that most services secure their APIs (with a secret key) vs the way Apple push notification services uses custom certificates - what's the advantange/reason/disadvantage of using a certificate to secure your api service?

Answer (score 0):

A secret key can normally be reverse engineered if you have access to something that uses the API.

If a system using certificates has been implemented correctly then information sent from the service can be cryptographically verified. For example Apple probably do it so that a bad actor cannot push notifications pretending that they are from Apple.

Comment: in my scenario I'm assuming that the secret key is shared with the partner, same as the certificate.  The credentials are used to push msgs from the partner to Apple not the other way around.  The push to clients has security handled by other means